# Django Factory Boy letter generator

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

How can I create a letter generator instead number one?

For example:

```
username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user-%r' % n)
```

I need 'user-a', not 'user-1'. Maybe I try to use string.ascii_lowercase, but I don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What about sequence index?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user-%r' % ascii_lowercase[n])
```

Be aware if n > 25 (that is "z") **IndexError** will be raised.